# Making object "fatter" in the middle

Tags: modeling

So I'm designing shape of candle in Blender and I need to make it fatter, but only in lower part. The crucial part is to keep a smooth transition between this fatter part and the rest of candle plus also the spring around the candle has to be resized in the same way, together with the core part.

Object now:
[image]

Shape I would like to obtain:
[image]

Answer (score 6):

You can use a *Mesh Deform* modifier: Give the modifier to your cylinder, create a cube object that will be *Mesh Deform* object, loop cut it at its bottom, click on the *Bind* button, scale up the edge loop at the bottom of your cube object, it will deform the cylinder:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this modifier worked. I only had to use it on both cylinder and spiral separately. Thanks!

Comment: Oh ok i didnt know these were 2 separate objects, you could have joined them with Ctrl J