# How to mash an object into another?

Tags: modeling

[image]

I'm trying to smash the bottom of a cylinder on a body, so the bottom part of the cylinder will be a bit bigger than the higher part

[image]

It's like you push the prong into the body, his bottom part expand, I tried using the sculpt mode but it looks so weird

Blender File: https://drive.google.com/file/d/14dMof-8dervh-4IriATW18kHEtWxJVqe/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Hello, are you trying to animate? Also, it's very hard to understand how your objects look like in your image, do you have another one? Maybe use the Mesh Deform modifier, see here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/288787/making-object-fatter-in-the-middle/288788#288788

Comment: @moonboots i'm not trying to animate, i'll try the mesh deform modifier and tell you if it works

Comment: i feel like the mesh deform modifier will look weird, i'll try to animate it

Comment: nah i'm dumb i don't know what to do

Comment: Your topology is rather bad, a lot of triangles, also the final shape seems rather easy to model, why don't you do it from scratch? Or select the bottom of your object and simply scale it up so that it appears larger?

Comment: @moonboots It's done by my boss on Rhinogold, i can't touch the model too much nor do it by myself (if i could i would), i'll do the scaling technique seems to be the easier path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable the *Proportional Editing* option, select the bottom of your shape (<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> to switch to X-ray visibility and select through, <kbd>B</kbd> to box select):

[image]

Scale up with <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> so that it only scales on X and Y, scroll to get the *Proportional Editing* influence radius you  want:

[image]

To give the exact same mesh to the other similar objects, select them all, at the end shift select the modified one (as it is selected at last it becomes the active object) and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> (*Link/Transfer Data > Object Data*):

[image]